# Unexpected behaivor: Database.insert(userList, false) is rolling back User insertion

Tags: query, insert, database.insert

I am attempting to insert two users with the database.insert method. One user that should work, and another that is missing required fields.

```
// Create two users, one of which is missing a required field
User[] users = new List<User>{
   new User(FirstName='Test',
            LastName = 'User',
            Email = 'some_email@email.com,
            Username = 'some_unique_username',
            Alias = 'tuser',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', 
            ProfileId = '00e3h000001YUCZAA4', 
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
            ),
    new User ()};
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(users, false);

// Iterate through each returned result
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted account. User ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('User fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, when the code is executed, I receive on Successful message with the User Id, for the first user, and one error message, for the second user. Strangely, when I attempt to query for the first User or find them in the database they do not exist. Even more strangely, when I do not attempt to insert the user that produces the error, then the first user is successfully inserted and DOES exist in the database. My understanding is that Database.insert(users, false) should not rollback insertions when there is an error, but in this case it seems to be doing just that. How is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible that there is another error occurring somewhere within the execution context that is causing a rollback? When I run the code above anonymously, the first user is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you need to set the username and email for the first user. You aren't seeing the first user because the email and username are not set therefore the record is not created.

```
User[] users = new List<User>{
    new User(FirstName='Test',
            LastName = 'User',
            Email = 'some_email@email.com,
            Username = 'some_unique_username',
            Alias = 'tuser',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', 
            ProfileId = '00e3h000001YUCZAA4', 
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
            ),
    new User ()};
```

With this first user will insert and the second one will fail, but the first user will still be there.

Comment: You are correct, but I unfortunately had some logic elsewhere in my code to determine those fields. I have since to took your answer an added it to the question as an edit. For the sake of the question, you can consider those fields added. The same strange behavior applies regardless.